# Android Emulator was working but now stopped

Tags: android

Emulator on Android studio was loading up Apps fine, now it comes up with an error message, it still loads but with no app on it. Logical below,

```
04-30 07:13:40.285 2864-2864/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
04-30 07:13:40.495 1959-1959/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ChimeraRcvrProxy: Chimera config error: com.google.android.chimera.config.InvalidConfigException: No registered Chimera receiver impl for ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.phenotype.receiver.PhenotypeBroadcastReceiver}
04-30 07:13:41.663 1959-2172/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/GCoreUlr: Bad errorId configuring silent feedback
04-30 07:13:41.975 1959-2172/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/GCoreUlr: Bad errorId configuring silent feedback
04-30 07:13:42.235 2271-2324/com.google.android.gms I/Icing: Done compaction min disk 0.000% min index 99.988% num docs 50 old 62 trimmed 0 err 0
04-30 07:13:48.305 1175-1545/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13
```

)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

its already happened with me so i did this

> clean your project and create another virtual device and if you can
>   update your gradle